# Load module inside module programatically Joomla 3

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, jfactory

I was wondering how can we load a module inside a module, in Joomla 3 programatically.

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

After some digging I found this code. Most pages I visited are using outdated code, here is the one that worked for me.

```
$doc      = JFactory::getDocument();
$renderer = $doc->loadRenderer('modules');
$position = 'moduleposition';
$options  = array('style' => 'raw');
echo $renderer->render($position, $options, null);
```

Comment: Now I wonder how to load by module id...